# Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array.map() arrow function and have the following error:
"Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function array-callback-return"

Here is my code:

```
          {productList.map((val) => {
            const category = val.CategoryName;
            // const quantity = val.ProductQuantity
            if (category === "MotorcycleParts") {
              if (val.ProductQuantity !== 0) {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="buyNowBtnDiv">
                        {localStorage.getItem("username") === "" ||
                        localStorage.length === 0 ? (
                          <div id="buyAddBtn">
                          </div>
                        ) : (
                          <div id="buyAddBtn">
                          </div>
                        )}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            }
          })}
```

I have read about the error and I see it has something to do with requiring a returning value, but I do have this?

A code example with a fix would help, I think it would be something simple.

Comment: for a quick fix you can add a return null after the end of the last if block

Answer (score 4):

You could just return null when the listed conditions are not matched:

```
          {productList.map((val) => {
        const category = val.CategoryName;
        // const quantity = val.ProductQuantity
        if (category === "MotorcycleParts") {
          if (val.ProductQuantity !== 0) {
            return (
              <div>
                <div>
                  <div class="buyNowBtnDiv">
                    {localStorage.getItem("username") === "" ||
                    localStorage.length === 0 ? (
                      <div id="buyAddBtn">
                      </div>
                    ) : (
                      <div id="buyAddBtn">
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          }
         return null;
        }
      })}
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the reply.

Answer (score 4):

`map` has to return a value for each item.

If you want to do some filtering, you should consider using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) before, so you can remove the `if`s in your map.

The code is also way more easy to read.

```
      {productList.filter(val => val.CategoryName === "MotorcycleParts" && val.ProductQuantity !== 0)
                  .map((val) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <div>
                  <div class="buyNowBtnDiv">
                    {localStorage.getItem("username") === "" ||
                    localStorage.length === 0 ? (
                      <div id="buyAddBtn">
                      </div>
                    ) : (
                      <div id="buyAddBtn">
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
      })}
```

Comment: Never thought of this, how Interesting.

Comment: Even though this suggestion has a clean look, I must say that I'm not a fan since it creates two rounds of iteration when you could have just a map like the original (productList.filter iterates through the original array to create a new array that is then iterated with map).

Comment: You're assuming having `null` values is acceptable though. It's not always the case.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the reply.